# Delete raises integrity error

Tags: sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I have 2 tables:

- `Users` with `U_Id` as primary key
- `Votes` with `V_author` which refers to `Users(U_Id)` as foreign key

Question: How to delete rows from `Users` table?
When I try to do that I get the error below.

> Error: psycopg2.IntegrityError: update or delete on table "users"
>   violates foreign key constraint "votes_v_author_fkey" on tabl e
>   "votes" DETAIL:  Key (u_id)=(7) is still referenced from table
>   "votes".

Comment: The reason is [Database Referencial integrity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity). Suppose you have user with `U_id` 1, and Vote with `Users`  1. If you remove that User (with Id 1) from `Users` table,then vote with `Users` 1 become Invalid, since it References user which has `U_id` 1 but that user does not exists.

Answer (score 1):

As described in the error, there is a record in `Votes` table, which refers to about to be deleted record from `Users` table. You need to delete the records from child table first:

```
DELETE FROM Votes WHERE v_author = 7
```